# android.content.ActivityNotFoundException but declared in Manifest

Tags: android, android-activity, android-manifest

I have the following in my manifest file:

```
 <activity
            android:name="org.sipdroid.codecs.Codecs$CodecSettings"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
 </activity>
```

And this is the class:

```
public static class CodecSettings extends PreferenceActivity {

    private static final int MENU_UP = 0;
    private static final int MENU_DOWN = 1;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.codec_settings);

        // for long-press gesture on a profile preference
        registerForContextMenu(getListView());

        addPreferences(getPreferenceScreen());
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v,
                    ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {
        super.onCreateContextMenu(menu, v, menuInfo);

        menu.setHeaderTitle(R.string.codecs_move);
        menu.add(Menu.NONE, MENU_UP, 0,
             R.string.codecs_move_up);
        menu.add(Menu.NONE, MENU_DOWN, 0,
             R.string.codecs_move_down);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

        int posn = (int)((AdapterContextMenuInfo)item.getMenuInfo()).position;
        Codec c = codecs.elementAt(posn);
        if (item.getItemId() == MENU_UP) {
            if (posn == 0)
                return super.onContextItemSelected(item);
            Codec tmp = codecs.elementAt(posn - 1);
            codecs.set(posn - 1, c);
            codecs.set(posn, tmp);
        } else if (item.getItemId() == MENU_DOWN) {
            if (posn == codecs.size() - 1)
                return super.onContextItemSelected(item);
            Codec tmp = codecs.elementAt(posn + 1);
            codecs.set(posn + 1, c);
            codecs.set(posn, tmp);
        }
        PreferenceScreen ps = getPreferenceScreen();
        SharedPreferences sp = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(Receiver.mContext);
        String v = "";
        SharedPreferences.Editor e = sp.edit();

        for (Codec d : codecs)
            v = v + d.number() + " ";
        e.putString(Settings.PREF_CODECS, v);
        e.commit();
        ps.removeAll();
        addPreferences(ps);
        return super.onContextItemSelected(item);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onPreferenceTreeClick(PreferenceScreen ps, Preference p) {
        ListPreference l = (ListPreference) p;
        for (Codec c : codecs)
            if (c.key().equals(l.getKey())) {
                c.init();
                if (!c.isLoaded()) {
                    l.setValue("never");
                    c.fail();
                    l.setEnabled(false);
                    l.setSummary(l.getEntry());
                    if (l.getDialog() != null)
                        l.getDialog().dismiss();
                }
            }
        return super.onPreferenceTreeClick(ps,p);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        unregisterForContextMenu(getListView());
    }
}
```

I'm getting :
    Unable to find explicit activity class {org.sipdroid.sipua/org.sipdroid.codecs.Codecs$CodecSettings}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?

What's wrong?

Comment: Check the package name at the top of your `CodecSettings` activity, if it matches with the entry in manifest for that activity name or not !!

Comment: in manifest:     package="org.sipdroid.sipua"

in codecs:      package org.sipdroid.codecs;

Comment: post the package name at the top of your `CodecSettings` activity here along with the gradle `applicationId` for your app

Comment: CodecSettings: package org.sipdroid.codecs;

Gradle Application ID: applicationId "org.sipdroid.sipua"

Comment: Activity shouldn't be static. This is bad practice.

Comment: In manifest replace old `org.sipdroid.codecs.Codecs$CodecSettings` to `org.sipdroid.codecs.CodecSettings` and see if this works

Comment: CodecSettings is an inner class within Codecs. If i replace it like you said it will be a syntax error

Comment: @JavadKhan  I tried also to make it non static in a separate class. Same results

Comment: Just delete it, without any reason, When it comes to your problem. Activity shouldn't be an inner class. Extract it to new class if this is inner class. And then declare in Manifest file. But pay attention to Activity path (I mean package name).

Comment: @JavadKhan I did that. But the problem still occurs

Comment: try @JavadKhan solution and try not using static nested classes as they have a lifetime of their own and can cause leaks

Comment: org.sipdroid.sipua/org.sipdroid.codecs.Codecs$CodecSettings   This shows, you declared package name second time. Use  "." instead of package name.

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with any of this code. The only thing I can think of is that the class is not present in your APK. You can use APKtool to look in your APK and see if the class is present. It may also have been obfuscated in which case the name will be mangled and it won't match your manifest.

Answer (score -1):

**1** Activity shouldn't be a static class.

**2** Activity shouldn't be an inner class.

When it comes to your problem, it shows that, you declared package name twice.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.yourpackage.activities">

    <application
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

        <activity android:name=".MainActivity"> 
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

    </application>

</manifest>
```

If you declared package name in `<manifest ../>` , you don't need declare it again in `<activity android:name=".MainActivity">` . Just use "." instead of that.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with declaring an `Activity` as `static` inner class. If it is an inner class it **must be declared `static` otherwise the Android framework will not be able to instantiate it.**

Comment: Also, the package name in the `<manifest>` tag has nothing to do with the Java package name used in the source code. These **may be the same, but it are not required to be the same.** In this case, OP has specified the name of his `Activity` correctly in the manifest.